# Setting the height of stack layout widget

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a stack layout/widget inside which I have for ex. 10 Positioned child widgets. Each child widget is given a top position of +40 pixel ie. The first child's top position is 0, the 2nd child's top position is 40, the 3rd child's top position is 80 and so on. So I have to set the height of the stack layout = (height of the child + (10*40)). How can I do that?

Example code:

```
class _CardStackState extends State<CardStackWidget> {
  List<Widget> cards;
  double lastCardElevation = 1.0;
  double lastCardYPosition = 0.0;

  void buildCards(BuildContext context) {
    this.cards = List();
    widget.cardHeaderBodyMap.forEach((header, body) {
      cards.add(_CardStackItem(
        header: header,
        body: body,
        cardElevation: lastCardElevation++,
        cardBackgroundColor: widget.cardBackgroundColor,
        cardCornerRadius: widget.cardCornerRadius,
        cardYPosition: lastCardYPosition,
        screenHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      ));
      lastCardYPosition += widget.cardHeaderHeight;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    buildCards(context);
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
        return SingleChildScrollView(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
            constraints: BoxConstraints(
              minHeight: viewportConstraints.maxHeight,
            ),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                (widget.headerWidget != null)
                    ? widget.headerWidget
                    : Container(),
                Container(
                  height: 1000,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4.0),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: cards,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

See height of the container, I have set it to 1000, I have to set the actual height there. If I can able to determine the height of a card then I can do that.

Comment: why don't you use MediaQuery.of(context).size.height?

Comment: And what exactly that statement will return? The height of the device screen?

Comment: yes, it will return the size of your screen

Comment: I dont want that value. I want the remaining available space. For example there's a widget at the top whose height is 140px, so I want the remaining available height. How can I get that height?

Comment: I wrote a post about that :) https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-widget-size-and-position-b0a9ffed9407

Comment: I have read your post yesterday. That didnt help in my situation.

Comment: why not? :) you can get the size from any renderobject

Comment: btw, what do you want to achieve? do you have a gif/image about what you need?  why don't use listview or column+expanded elements?

Comment: I am creating my own layout as described by the designer of our company. I have created that layout library in Java android but I am new to flutter and I have to rewrite that layout.

Comment: could you add an image(screenshot) to your question?

Comment: Sorry, I cant. If it were my project I could have posted.